# How to mark up an online event with Schema.org for Google?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have used the [`Event`](https://schema.org/Event) schema for describing an **online event**, but Google asks for [`location`](https://schema.org/location) as a required property.

Which schema would you use? 
And if you used the `Event` schema, how would you set the `location` property?

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "This is the event name",
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "performer" : {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name" : "Daniel G.",
        "additionalName" : "Dani",
        "description": "This is my description"
    },
    "description": "This is the description of the event",
    "startDate": "2017-06-03T14:38:00+02:00",
    "endDate": "2017-06-03T15:08:00+02:00",
    "duration": "PT30M",
    "inLanguage": "es",
    "image" : "http://example.com/image.jpg",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "price": 10,
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "url": "http://example.com"
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now additional markup available to describe online/offline events. For [Event](https://schema.org/Event) check out the new [eventAttendanceMode](https://schema.org/eventAttendanceMode) property which accepts values from at least the following options (enumeration): OfflineEventAttendanceMode, OnlineEventAttendanceMode, MixedEventAttendanceMode.

Answer (score 1):

According [this example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#online-event) you can use location as URL.

Answer (score 0):

[`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) is probably¹ the correct type for online events, too (and there is no other more suitable type available).

Google, [according to their documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events), supports their event rich result only for physical events.

So there’s nothing you could do to get a Google rich result for your online event.  You can of course keep the markup (and omit the `location` property).

---

¹ See the issue [*applicability of Event to online events e.g. consider Webinar subtype*](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/298).